# Not able to build the release build in react native android

Tags: react-native

Task :react-native-device-information:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-device-information:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\navee.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bad4888d8074cc6f9c866f449fedf067\appcompat-1.0.2\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have values for `compileSdkVersion` which are clashing in your `MY_PROJECT_NAME/build.gradle` file.

The first value you have looks something like this:

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
```

and further down you have some dependencies which are using/need a HIGHER `compileSdkVersion` value.

SOLUTION:
Try using the newest SDK, 29 as of this answer. Edit your `project/build.gradle` (although instead of `project` you will have a folder named for your specific React Native project/app).

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
    ...
}
```

I got this information here:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/setup-sdk#update-build

Explanation:
If some package/dependency you're using needs to be able to use certain android APIs that are only available in SDK 29+ but your `project/build.gradle` is saying "use SDK 27", your dependencies would be expecting to use APIs which wouldn't exist.

Comment: what if it's the other way around? for example, dependency is quite outdated and requires older SDK version but the project uses the latest SDK version?

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x There are two values that will come into play:
`minSdkVersion`: the lowest API level with which your app is compatible.  This is the LOWEST android sdk that has all of the APIs you're using.
`targetSdkVersion`: highest API level against which you’ve designed and tested your app.

More information: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms